# Managing timed threads in C#.net

Tags: .net, multithreading, caching, frameworks

I am struggling with this question for some time now.

On my website, the user is asked to take a test. When he submits an answer, I call a WCF service which pushes his data in the database. This is quite simple but does become DB intensive as number of users increase.

So, to improve the performance (to avoid heavy calling to DB), I have -

a. Implemented caching in the service.

b. Implemented threading (for async working) - to push the cache data to the DB.

So, now, whenever a call to save the answer comes, it stores data in the service cache. Parallely, I run a thread (because I want to push the data to DB only once - at the finish of the user's test - and add the interim answer data in the cache), and I return the call as I don't want the user to be kept waiting. The thread I run has to have a timeout of 15mins. If the user doesn't submit any answer within 15mins, the cached results should be saved to DB. Till now it is simple and have managed to do this.

Where I am stuck is that if the user sends some answer and a call is made to the service within those 15mins, the timeout of that thread should be reset to next 15mins. So, its kinda sliding timer for a thread.

I have googled a lot but there seems to be no way to keep track of a thread. And, if I create a new thread on every save data request then it will just reproduce the same load on the DB.

I feel that if there could be some way to keep track of the thread that I first started and manipulate it accordingly, I will be able to achieve the desired thing.

Please advice and suggest.

With urgency and thanks

SV

Comment: How do you schedule the thread timeout? Do you block threads for 15 minutes? Are you sure db writes is your bottle neck, have you measured?

Comment: Albin, till now I have used System.Timer class timer, with setting to run once.

Answer (score 0):

You should answer Albin's query. Anyways you can try this:

When the user submits a query(WCF service call), save the time of the call in DB or some global object.

In the thread timeout logic calculate the difference between now and the time of last request.
If the difference is >= 15 release the thread, save data and create a new one. Else do not release.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you are opening a thread each time you add data to the cache. Can't you just add data to the cache and:

1. If the answer comes in, find the data in the cache and save to the DB.
2. Have a "cleanup" thread run every so often to look for data in the cache older than 15 minutes and save to the DB and clean the cache. **OR**
3. Have a 15 minute timer per data that you add to the cache that wakes up and cleans the cache if the data hasn't already been added to the DB.

It is never a good idea to block a thread for no reason and you should probably be using the ThreadPool if you are implementing a server - and blocking a ThreadPool thread is definitely not a good idea.

In any event, you should really make sure the DB is your bottleneck because you can run into a lot of trouble with your current design. For instance, what if the server crashes and hasn't saved the data in the database yet?